# How return value exec in table function without using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want return table function but error is

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

My code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_GetTable] 
     (@ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS 
      @Tbl TABLE (ID NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @str = 'SELECT * FROM support WHERE support IN ('+@ID+')'

    INSERT INTO @Tbl (ID)
        EXEC sp_executesql @str

    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedures including `sp_executesql` are forbidden in a UDF.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine

I don't see why you need dynamic here. Try

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_GetTable] (
 @ID as nvarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS 
@Tbl TABLE (
 ID nvarchar(MAX)
) AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO  @Tbl (ID)
    select * 
    from support  
    where support in (@ID)

RETURN 
END
```

If the parameter is supposed to represent a list you'd better use a UDT for that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/working-with-user-defined-types-in-sql-server . Demo

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.UDT_IDS AS TABLE (ID  NVARCHAR(MAX)) ;
```

and use it as a parameter

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_GetTable] (
 @IDS as dbo.UDT_IDS READONLY
)
RETURNS 
@Tbl TABLE (
 ID NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO  @Tbl (ID)
    SELECT support 
    FROM support  
    WHERE support in (SELECT ID FROM @IDS)

RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Presumably the parameter contains a comma delimited string in which case this won't work as desired.

Comment: @MartinSmith UDT table is the right tool  to pass a list as a parameter.